# Nested JSON dictionary where last level can be standard element or another dict

Tags: javascript, html, json, dictionary, knockout.js

so I have a JSON dictionary which I access using knockout js. The structure of the object is a nested dictionary but the last level contains some standard JSON `key:val` pairs and some dicts `key:{key1:val1, key2:val2}` which I am accessing dynamically to create a nested table. I know it sounds messy, but I need to do it (might not, if you have a better idea lmk)

```js
var dummy = {
    "Dummy Data": {
        "dummy1":{
            "dummy1.1":"val1",
            "dummy1.2":"val2",
            "dummy1.3":"val3"
        },
        "dummy2":{
            "dummy2.1":"val1",
            "dummy2.2":{
                "dummy2.2.1":"val2.1",
                "dummy2.2.2":"val2.2"
            },
            "dummy2.3":"val3"
        },
        "dummy3":{
            "dummy3.1":"val1",
            "dummy3.2":"val2"
        }
    }
}

function mapDictionaryToArray(dictionary) {
 var result = [];
 for (var key in dictionary) {
  if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result.push({ key: key, value: dictionary[key] }); 
  }  
 }
 return result;
}

ko.applyBindings(dummy);
```

```css
table {
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}

td, th {
 border: 1px solid #dddddd;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: mapDictionaryToArray(value)">
      <th data-bind="text: key"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: mapDictionaryToArray(value)">
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr data-bind="foreach: mapDictionaryToArray(value)">
            <td data-bind="text: key"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr data-bind="foreach: mapDictionaryToArray(value)">
            <td data-bind="text: value"></td>
          </tr>          
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

currently the table element with the dictionary instead of a direct value just says `[object Object]` but I would like a way to display maybe another table/break up the cell and fit in the rest of it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *entirely* sure what your desired result is, but I hope this helps:

To create nested structures, you can nest the `template` binding. This allows you to create a recursive pattern inside your views.

It helps if your data structure is already defined, so I made the `mapDictionaryToArray` method recursive as well. (This ensures you don't have to call the function in your binding handlers).

There's a `getTemplate` method that determines if a `value` is a "leaf" (last in tree), or a branch (needs another table).

```js
var dummy = {
  "Dummy Data": {
    "dummy1": {
      "dummy1.1": "val1",
      "dummy1.2": "val2",
      "dummy1.3": "val3"
    },
    "dummy2": {
      "dummy2.1": "val1",
      "dummy2.2": {
        "dummy2.2.1": "val2.1",
        "dummy2.2.2": "val2.2"
      },
      "dummy2.3": "val3"
    },
    "dummy3": {
      "dummy3.1": "val1",
      "dummy3.2": "val2"
    }
  }
}

function mapDictionaryToArray(dictionary) {
  var result = [];
  for (var key in dictionary) {
    if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var value = dictionary[key];

      result.push({
        key: key,
        value: isObj(value) ?
          mapDictionaryToArray(value) :
          value
      });
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function isObj(data) { 
  return data.toString() === "[object Object]";
}

function getTemplate(data) {
  return Array.isArray(data) ?
    "t-branch" :
    "t-leaf";
}

ko.applyBindings({
  firstObj: mapDictionaryToArray(dummy)[0],
  getTemplate: getTemplate
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

td { 
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { data: firstObj, name: 't-table' }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="t-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th data-bind="text: key"></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template: {
      name: $root.getTemplate(value), 
      data: value 
    }">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>


<script type="text/html" id="t-branch">
  <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
    <td data-bind="template: {
      name: 't-table',
      data: $data 
    }"></td>
  </tr>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="t-leaf">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
  </tr>
</script>
```